# Can i run Jasmine tests in JSFiddle?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, jsfiddle

I want to use JSFiddle to demonstrate a piece of code that includes AngularJS and a Jasmine unit test.

I've found several examples of people usnig JSFiddle with AngularJS and Jasmine, however **when I click Run in JSFiddle nothing seems to happen.**

Should I be able to run a Jasmine test from within JSFiddle and actually see the test results in the Results window?

Here's a page I found with a bunch of examples of using AngularJS, Jasmine and JSFiddle.  I've looked at a few of these in JSFiddle an in each case clicking Run does apparently nothing.
http://eitanp461.blogspot.com/2013/05/javascript-unit-testing-jasmine-and.html

Am I doing something wrong?  Is my expectation that I should see something in Results incorrect?

Comment: checking the console it says that jasmine files are not linked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should have worked on JSFiddle as well provided required resource files to be linked properly and 
Checking the console it says that `linked files are not found` 

[image]

---

and checking the link [jasmine.js](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js) yeah it's not available 
[image]

It might be 'coz of the fact that they have moved their pages so I would suggest you to download required files from [jasmine github resource](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/tree/master/dist) and then test on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually use that fiddle with support jasmine v2.0 - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dspigarelliMNDNT/2bo511uo/)

```
describe("first suite", function() {
    it('must throw Error', function () {
        expect(101).toBeLarge();
        expect(function() {
            throw new Error('A basePath must be set.')
        }).toThrow(new Error('A basePath must be set.'));
    });
});
```

This is works for me.